# Graphical issues and missing recovery mode after unplugging drive

Tags: linux-mint, grub2, dual-boot, graphics

I bought a new SSD for a laptop I ordered, and after getting it in the mail I decided to put it in my desktop so I could make sure it was recognized in BIOS and it didn't get damaged in shipping. After doing this GRUB is missing the ability to load into recovery mode, and my graphics drivers (both Nvidia and nouveau) are not rendering graphics properly. (both in-game and desktop effects)

My setup is a dual boot of Linux Mint 18.3 on an SSD, and Windows 10 installed on a separate SSD. I unplugged my Windows 10 SSD and plugged in the new SSD I got in the mail, booted into BIOS and checked if it was recognized in the list of boot devices. I shut the system down, reinserted the Windows 10 SSD and booted back up. I got an error stating master boot record not found. Going into the BIOS I noticed the mint boot record was installed to the seperate Windows 10 SSD, and there were 5 listings for ubuntu (238475MB), meaning my boot device list looks like:

> ubuntu(238475MB) (5X)
>
> Windows Boot Manager (P4: Samsung SSD)
>
> Ubuntu (P4: Samsung SSD)
>
> drives with no MBR

The P4: Samsung SSD devices are the only ones which will boot. However, when booting into Mint GRUB no longer shows the option to boot Linux Mint in recovery mode. It only shows regular boot and advanced options. The Samsung SSD with no boot record indication was set as the first priority boot device.

When booting into Linux Mint, Cinnamon would now constantly crash on startup. I managed to work around this in 2 different ways:

Setting graphics drivers (using driver manager) to xserver-nouveau, or when using Nvidia-384 drivers by delaying startup of desktop widgets (Docky) by 1 second. However both drivers suffer from laggy desktop effects like zooming out to show all workspaces, occasional screen tearing when scrolling, and missing graphics and white blocks in video games. Unplugging my secondary display has not fixed this. I also booted into Windows to make sure this isn't an issue with my graphics card (GTX1070), which is not the case.

- Are the GRUB and graphics issues related?
- Is it abnormal for GRUB to be installed on the drive which contains Windows?
- Should I install GRUB on the Linux drive? And if so, what's the best way to do this?

Comment: Please post the output of `lsblk -a -fs` as it is hard to figure out what you are referring to as different drives. It's a good idea to not make any changes until you figured out what is going on.

Comment: Please stop downvoting questions from those who are having problems. The purpose of this resource is to help. By downvoting you re **not** helping anyone. Downvoting is not for expressing you disliking the situation.

Comment: @ajeh
[here](https://i.imgur.com/aks9mks.png) is the output. sdb is the drive containing the Windows installation. sdd and sdc are drives used for storage.

Comment: I would recommend 2 things: 1) do a clean reinstall of your Linux with only that drive attached; 2) since you have 2 separate physical drives for each OS do not use Grub to dual boot - use the BIOS F12 key. I had a misfortune of finding out that the developer of Grub2 does not care about anyone using dual boot with Windows, and is unwilling to look into bug reports and fix issues. With that attitude anything is possible. If your kernel startup parameters somehow changed, that could explain graphics issues you are having.

Comment: But in general, this all sounds like an unrelated hardware problem introduced by messing with cables inside the case. It may help to clean everything of dust, wipe card connectors with alcohol and reinsert all add-on cards and cables.